# what is the matching strategy of commands in shell like bash and zsh?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, zshrc

I am now using zsh shell, but I assume that its matching strategy of commands is the same as bash. Here is the thing:

I want to make an alias command, which create a new .cpp file using a template file and take the first argument as the new file name. I also write an alias for Java template.

Here are the functions in .*zshrc*:

```
function cppgen()
{
  cp ~/Documents/Templates/cpp_template.cpp ./$1.cpp
  vim ./$1.cpp
}

function javagen()
{
  cp ~/Documents/Templates/java_template.java ./$1.java
  vim ./$1.java
}
```

Weiredly, only the **javagen** alias works. When I use **cppgen**, the shell prints:

```
usage: cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvX] source_file target_file
       cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvX] source_file ... target_directory
```

After struggling for a while, I finally realized that the shell treats my **cppgen** command as **cp**. After I changed the alias name from **cppgen** to **cgen**, everything works fine.

So does it mean that shell doesn't try to match the exact command but the shortest matching command(I guess)?

Comment: I haven't used zsh much, but I'd be very surprised if a function named `cppgen` were to override the `cp` command. How exactly did you invoke your `cppgen` function (with what argument(s))?

Comment: Show the results of calling `cppgen` -- with a realistic example of your usage mode -- after running `set -x`.

Comment: Aliases take priority over functions;  take a look at your list of aliases and see if you already have  cppgen defined as an alias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for the comments. Now I could set alias as **cppgen**. I didn't change anything.
Not sure what happened... Maybe I need more coffee before posting in StackOverflow.